# How to position button at the bottom of the boostrap 4 card?

Tags: alignment, vertical-alignment, card

Is it possible to place button on the vertical end of the boostrap card? Cards are filling automatically with empty space to remain all with the same height, but how to place a button at the end of the card no matter on height of the specific card?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the button to the card footer (card-footer class in Bootstrap) and style the footer background color and border so that visually it seems as a part of card body.
check this out:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/zaaraa-z/pen/PopzqGz)

```css
.card {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card-header {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0 !important;
  background-color: #FCCF23 !important;
}

.card-footer {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.card-footer p {
  display: none;
}

.card-footer button {
  color: #FCCF23;
  background-color: #52134B;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.card-footer button:hover {
  color: #52134B;
  background-color: #FCCF23;
  transition: all .5;  
}



/*delete the following codes to make footer totally invisible*/
.card-footer {
  border-top: dashed 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05) !important;
}
.card-footer p {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="card b-0 w-50 m-5 text-center">
      <h4 class="card-header border-0 p-4">I am a Bootstrap Card Header</h4>
      <p class="card-body p-4">I am a Bootstrap card Body. You can add as many texts as you want here, yet, the button will be remained at the bottom of the card!</p>
      <div class="card-footer pt-0 pb-4 px-4">
        <p class="my-2">I am an 'invisible' Bootstrap Card Footer</p>
        <button type="submit">hover me!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```